# ppp connection terminated: "No network protocols running"

Tags: linux, modem, ppp

I am new to ppp protocol and its configuration and got a problem that ppp connection terminated, no ppp0 created.

This modem(telit lm960a18) works fine with this sim card and APN using network manager in VM. since there is no nmcli nor mmcli in my hardware, but ppp is available, I need to make ppp connection work on this board.

I suspect the reason it terminates is **'No network protocols running'**, but cannot figure how to resolve it. Any help and directions are appreciated!

here is ppp.log message.

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/options finished (pid 12658), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 3
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4bca569a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x6 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x13647a80> <pcomp> <accomp>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x6 <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4bca569a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x7 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x13647a80> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x7 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x13647a80> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x8 magic=0x13647a80]
rcvd [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Connection terminated.
```

options file

```
# Run in foreground (lets s6 supervisor work)
nodetach
# Uncomment below to emit debug messages
debug
# Set to one failure allowed (no retries)
maxfail 1
# Lock the modem port when establishing PPP
lock
# no auth
noauth
# Log file location
logfile /opt/iprf/tmp/ppp.log
# Connect script
connect /etc/ppp/net-connect-cellVerizon
# No hardware flow control
nocrtscts
# Disable compression control protocol
noccp
# Disable IPCP negotiations
noip
# Modem port name
/dev/ttyUSB2
# Modem port baud rate
115200
```

/etc/ppp/net-connect-cellVerizon file

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/chat -v -t 60 -f /etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon
```

/etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon file

```
TIMEOUT 5
ABORT   'ERROR'
''
'AT'
OK
'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","so01.vzwstatic"'
OK
'ATD*99***1#'
CONNECT ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `noip` option, you are disabling IPCP (IP Control Protocol) negotiation, and thus IPv4 communication. So `pppd` won't ask for it.

You also don't have the `+ipv6` option to enable IPv6CP and IPv6. Apparently your `pppd` will not try for IPv6 unless specifically asked to.

And if I recall correctly, the side that's initiating the connection should state which network protocols it wants. You've specifically excluded IPv4, and haven't asked for IPv6 nor IPX, so there's apparently nothing left over.

The remote end also seems to be requesting CHAP authentication using the MD5 hash algorithm, but your `pppd` is rejecting it, probably because there are no applicable CHAP secrets (passwords) configured on your side.